# Linking to Oracle tables in Access using VB6: Error 3000?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vb6, vba, database-connection

I am trying to link an Oracle table to access using the following Visual Basic 6.0 code:

```
Dim objApp, objDB, objTable As Object
Dim strFile, strConnect, strLocalTable, strServerTable As String

strFile = "C:\path\to\base.mdb"
strLocalTable = "local"
strServerTable = "BASE.TABLE_NAME"
strConnect = "ODBC;Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};ConnectString=name.world;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"


Set objApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objApp.OpenCurrentDatabase strFile
Set objDB = objApp.CurrentDb()
Set objTable = objDB.CreateTableDef(strLocalTable)

objTable.Connect = strConnect
objTable.SourceTableName = strServerTable
objDB.TableDefs.Append objTable 'Generates 3000 Error
objDB.TableDefs.Refresh
```

On the second to last row I get (loosely translated from swedish by me) "Run time error 3000: Reserved error (-7778). There is no message for this error."

Any ideas on why this may be? I am told this code has worked before, so it could possibly be some kind of version conflict with updated software. The database is in Access 2000 format, and Access 2013 is installed on the computer (however, saving the database as Access 2013 does not help). Or is there something wrong with the connection string perhaps?

**EDIT:** I tried using a DSN in the connection string:

```
strConnect = "ODBC;Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};DSN='test';"
```

I get the same error, even though I can use that very DSN to link the tables manually in Access.

Also (as I stated in the comments) changing some of the information in the connection string (like deliberately providing an incorrect username) leads to a different error (3146: Connection failed). This leads me to believe that the connection to the database works, since it seems to be able to differentiate between good and bad credentials.

Comment: That connection string doesn't look right - in particular, the `ConnectString` should be of the format `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=7001))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myDb)))`. [Check here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/) for the correct format. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried copying a string of the format you suggested from the tnsnames.ora file, and it did not help. Instead I got another error message (3151: Could not connect to...). I get the same error for all the formats suggested at the page you linked to.

I think the format in the question works for connecting to the database, since when I change values of ConnectString, Uid or Pwd to incorect ones it gives me another error message (3146: Connection failed).

Answer (score 1):

Try this connection string and leave out the 'world.' part

ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in orahome32};UID=userId;PWD=password;SERVER=servername;dbq=servername

(I was having trouble earlier today with connections that left the dbq out)

Or maybe your existing one will work, but regardless...I think Access likes you to create the table default in one swoop and not break things up so.....

Instead of this:

```
Set objTable = objDB.CreateTableDef(strLocalTable)

objTable.Connect = strConnect
objTable.SourceTableName = strServerTable
```

Try This:

```
Set objTable = objDB.CreateTableDef(strLocalTable, dbAttachSavePWD, strServerTable, strConnect)
```

(NOTE: the dbAttachSavePWD will help avoid users getting prompted for password every time they touch the table; leave it out if that is not desired)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So far I have had no luck, though. Your connection string gives me 3146: Connection failed errors. I don't think I have the "Oracle in orahome32" driver installed so I should try and find that one first before I give up, though. The more compact CreateTableDef gives me the same error as before (3000, unkown) when it comes to the Append line. I still greatly appreciate the effort.

Comment: Ahh, shucks. If you're able to manually link the table(s) into that mdb, them maybe you can copy the table(s) over to other database(s) instead of creating them? You can do a make table on a remote database using the query wizard or run the following SQL: SELECT BASE_TABLE_NAME.* INTO base IN 'C:\path\to\base.mdb' FROM BASE_TABLE_NAME;